# Reduce memory footprint in the construction of a BigInt class

Tags: c++, types, biginteger, template-specialization, memory-footprint

I'm working on a concept at the moment and I'm writing the Pseudo code as I am asking this question. I'm thinking of making a fairly easy and simple to use class interface to represent BigInts. I'm thinking of making a couple of simple structures with basic properties and members that the BigInt class would use. For example instead of the BigInt class handling negative values directly it would contain a Sign struct and this struct would basically contain either a value of 0 or 1, or basically a Boolean type to designate if this BigInt is positive or negative. Upon Construction I intend to have the class generate a positive by default. I would also like to have a struct that represents the digits where there are two variants. The first variant has the digits 0-9 and the second which would inherit the original but also includes A-F. This way the class which would be a template class but only ever has two valid types would support use for Decimal and Hexadecimal. All of the mathematical operators would be defined outside of the class and depending its inferred type it will call and perform the appropriate version of the function. However the Hexadecimal part is still only concept as I'd like to get the Decimal version up and running first. These helper classes might look something like this:

```
class Sign {
private:
    bool isNegative_ { false };
    char sign_;
public:
    Sign() : isNegative_( false ) {
        sign_ = '+';
    }
    Sign( const bool isNegative ) : isNegative_( isNegative ) { 
        sign_ = isNegative_ ? '-' : '+';
    }; 

    Sign( const char sign ) {
        if ( sign == '+' || sign == '\0' || sign == ' ' ) {
            isNegative_ = false;
        } else if ( sign == '-' ) {
            isNegative_ = true;
        } else {
            // throw error improper character.
        }
    }

    bool isPostive() const { return !isNegative_; }
    bool isNegative() const { return !isNegative; }

    char sign() const { return sign_; }
    char negate() {
        isNegative_ = !isNegative_;
        sign_ = isNegative_ ? '+' : '-'; 
        return sign_;         
    }        
};

// NST = NumberSystemType
class enum NST { Decimal = 10, Hexadecimal = 16 };

template<class NT> // NT = NumberType
class Digit {
private:
    NST nst_; // determines if Decimal or Hexadecimal       
};

// Specialization for Decimal
template<NST::Decimal> // Should be same as template<10>
class Digit {
    // would like some way to define 4 bits to represent 0-9; prefer not to
    // use bitfields, but I think a char or unsigned char would be wasting 
    // memory using twice as much for what is needed. Not sure what to do here...
    // maybe std::bitset<>...


};

template<NST::Hexadecimal> // Should be same as template<16>
class Digit : public Digit<Decimal> { // Also inherits all of The first specialization.
    // same as above only needs 4 bits to represent values form 0-F
    // A half char would be excellent but does not exist in c++... and most
    // programming language's types.
    // still thinking of maybe std::bitset<>...

};
```

The main distinction between the two is that the first specialization would only allow digits values from 0-9 and the digits themselves 0-9 where the second doesn't have that restriction, but also allows from a-f and or A-F either case is valid. I may also include a const char* to designate the Hex Prefix of `0x` that would be appended to any contained value for display.

I like this design approach as I'd like to keep the actual arithmetic functions and operators of the BigInt class as seperate function templates since the BigInt class can support both Decimal and Hexadecimal specialized template types. Also down the road if everything goes properly I'd also like to add the support to work with Complex numbers as well.

The BigInt class would be like this:

```
template<class NT>
BigInt {
private:
    Sign sign_;
    Digit<NT> carryDigit_;
    std::vector<Digit<NT>> value_;

    // May contain some functions such as setters and getters only
    // Do not want the class to be modifying itself except for assignment only.
};
```

And as above this would be specialized as well for Decimal and Hexadecimal Types, however if someone creates an instance of BigInt<> myBigInt this should default to Decimal!

For the data that is contained in the vector. I'd like to store the digits in reverse order of what one reads. So if their is a number `345698` in BigInt's internal vector it would be stored as `896543`. The reason for this is when we do arithmetic operations in math we work from the least significant to the most significant starting at the right on the left side of the decimal point which is irrelevant since this is a BigInt only class and we work our way to the left. However if we store each digit that can only be 0-9 in each element of the above class's vector in the proper order and we use an outside operator+() function this would be challenging to do for one BigInt to another... example:

```
Basic Arithmetic R - L    | Vector storing standard
12345                       <1,2,3,4,5>
+ 678                       <6,7,8>
------  
13023
```

Here the indexes of <5> & <8> do not coincide so this makes it tough to figure out how to add a value with a few digits to one with many. My approach is that if we store the number in reverse order:

```
                         | Vector stored in reverse
                           <5,4,3,2,1>
                           <6,7,8>
```

Then the addition becomes simple! All we have to do is add each digit from both BigInt's vectors by same index value. And we have the use of the carry digit to carry over to the next field. The resulting BigInt would return with a size that is at least equal to or greater than the largest of the two BigInts. If the carryDigit has a value then the operation of addition on the next iteration will include 3 additions instead of two. Now when getting the BigInt for display we can return either a vector> except that when the user gets it this is not a "BigInt" it is vector of Digits and it is also in the correct order. It can even be returned by a string representation. This class can be constructed by a vector> and it will reverse the order when it stores it internally.

This is the overall concept of my BigInt class, I'm just wondering if this is a good design plan, if it would be considered efficient and I guess the main question that I have is about what to use to store the actual digits within the Digit's class... Would `std::bitset<>` be appropriate to conserve the memory foot print or would it just be better to use a `char` and not worry about the extra space with the pro of being simpler to implement?

Comment: Is this as an excersice or for production? Because there's a whole bunch of tried and true bigint libraries out there with C++ interfaces, e.g. [GMP](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface).

Comment: @Darkhuuk  I have already looked into `GMP` and it  is mostly for use with `C` and not friendly to `C++` even though there is a `C++` wrapper class to use `GMP`. However this is primarily for use on `Linux`. I'm on `Windows`. I've tried using `GMP` via `Cygwin` but was extremely difficult to work with being that many of its properties use `Bash` commands that I'm not all that familiar with.  `GMP` is no use to me and doesn't fit the flow or the need of my other classes.  It's for my own personal library of classes.

Comment: If I was going to implement my own large-integer, I would use a built-in type such as 32-bits to hold each "digit"...  essentially meaning my digit representation is base-2^32, rather than your proposal of base-10 or base-16.  All my operations would be in binary and there would be no wasted space.  So the entire number would just be something like `std::vector<uint32_t>`.  This makes converting to/from base-10 for Input/Output slightly more involved, but the math would be fast and vectorizable...  which to me is the whole point of big-int.

Comment: @Darhuuk  The function templates will not be a problem to write.  I'm just trying to figure out which would be better a better type as the basis of the Digits class to conserve memory and that is where I was thinking of `std::bitset<>` or just ignore the double non used memory for a faster implementation. For example if BigInt contains say 1million entries into its vector and the base type of Digits is a char, that  1byte x 1million. If I could figure out a way to only use 4 bits per digit then that would be (1byte x 1million) / 2 thus significantly reducing the memory footprint.

Comment: "A half char would be excellent but does not exist in c++..." It doesn't exist in assembler either, because it makes no sense for processors designed to deal with 32 or 64 bits at a time with some internal convenience to deal with 8 bits at a time. And `std::bitset` won't help you with that since it allocates storage in word-size blocks (at least in the GCC implementation).

Comment: @paddy hmm good point. It is the trade off between memory size versus efficiency of the algorithm...

Comment: Put it this way: how does the computer convert a base-10 string of digits to a 32-bit number and vice versa?  You've probably written code that does this before.  It's not much different -- you're just using more bits.  I bet I've even answered a question like this on Stack Overflow at some point.

Comment: @paddy well the idea of the template specialization was to make sure that the class is restricted so that each element of the BigInt's vector internally can only store from 0-9 in the Decimal version and the same in for 0-F in the Hex version. This way when doing the operations with the digits stored in reverse order, it becomes simple to do as you do a index to index operation and check for carry.

Comment: Well, it looks to me like you've looked at the problem, chosen an inappropriate solution and then over-engineered it.

Comment: @paddy well I didn't think I really over-engineered it. I've never written this kind of class or library before, but a design pattern came to mind and with my IDE currently not being available to me; I didn't want to lose my train of thought about it so I pretty much wrote the shells for the class, described what I was trying to do with them showing the pseudo code and needed some assistance on a small stumbling block... I was trying to reduce the amount of space it takes up but yet keeping it easy to implement and use while efficient as well.

Comment: @Darhuuk: well yes, but saying so is a bit like telling a song writer that there are already songs about love. <g> The approach to the implementation as given here seems to be very naive, though.

Comment: @FrancisCugler - I agree with paddy. Distinct types for hex and decimal is terribly flawed design. One requirement of integral types is being able to assign and compare them (e.g. for equality) to each other.  Your approach means the number of operations you need to implement is quadratic with number of bases you support - hard to maintain. Consider using a single class to efficiently represent an unsigned bigint value, then implement a signed bigint using that unsigned bigint type and a `bool` to represent sign. Handle bases at input or output, not with distinct representation in memory.

Comment: @Peter yeah I'm considering it. It was kind of late when the design came to mind and without my IDE present I couldn't write the code to do any testing on it and I didn't want to lose my train of thought. I'll revisit this tomorrow or the next day when I have some time, and I may keep some of it while discarding other parts. It's just a little to late in the evening for me to actually try and do the calculations in my head...

Comment: I didn't mean to belittle you for doing this, by the way.  I absolutely agree with trying things in code and having fun.  Since you are here asking for advice, however, it'd be good if those of us providing it felt like it was actually being received.  The main issue you have is trying to think of your numbers as base 10 digits, and that is compounded by you trying to find a compact data type representing a single digit in a template.  That was my point about over-engineering -- you're solving the wrong problem.  Seems like you're trapped in this mode of thinking.  Start fresh tomorrow.

Comment: @Francis: if you use a binary format, you can store 9 digits in 4 bytes, which is still better than using chars to store the numbers. Note that addition, division, etc. with integers is also much easier and faster than with digits.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's a new day and now that I'm actually up and able to think a little more clearly; yeah you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest addressable unit of memory in C++ is a byte, and a byte is *at least* 8 bits (and usually exactly 8 bits). So your idea indeed wastes memory.

I also suspect you're not that familiar with math. What you call "NumberSystemType" is ordinarily called the *base*. So we talk about base-10 or base-16.

Now base-10 is only useful for human consumption, and thus pointless for this sort of bigints. Humans can't deal with numbers that have more than about 20 decimal digits anyway. So, pick a base that's useful for computers. And pick one. There's no need to support multiple bases. As paddy points out, base 2^32 is a perfectly reasonable base for computers.

Comment: I understand the distinction of what you are saying about base-10 and base-16 due to Logarithms. I was just giving it a friendly readable name As base-10 which is Decimal is a Number System and base-16 which is Decimal is also a Number System. I'm trying to only store in the Decimal version of BigInt's container for each element 0-9 and nothing else but as for the Hexadecimal version it will store 0-F.  The reason for this is when writing the functions to do the addition - subtraction etc. they become quite easy if the digits are stored in the vector in reverse order!

Comment: About the smallest addressable unit of memory being 8bits or a 1 byte: I know that. I was wondering if there was a way to maybe use `bitset<>` instead of some union to say combine digit [0] and digit[1] into a single byte then digit[2] and digit[3] into a single byte. One being the low part and the other being the high part of the word.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: Oh, the idea of storing digits in reverse order is not bad. But that still works when you choose a reasonable base like 2^8 or 2^32. Choosing a too-small base like 2^4 is just adding problems without any benefits whatsoever.

Comment: so then if that's the case a simple `char` type would work then as the underlying type, or even a `short`!

Comment: Like I said I haven't written any code yet; as this was only a concept in my head and I don't have my IDE currently available and I didn't want to forget what my train of thought was so I basically wrote the shell and pseudo code of the design from scratch while asking this question.

Comment: If it's easier for you to think that way, then just go with char and work in base-256.  Storing in reverse order is therefore basically the same as what little-endian architectures do currently.  When you have a comfortable implementation, you might want to consider larger data-types to get better leverage from common architectures, and support vectorization / SIMD to do multiple calculations in parallel.

Comment: @paddy yeah I know about little-endian I own an Intel!

Comment: AMD supports that stuff too, you know.

Comment: yeah but I've always had Intels

Comment: Another thing is the reason I wanted to only have 0-9 as a single element of each vector is that I don't want a vector to contain this: `< 9, 2334343, 235, 03, 243, >` as that would not suite my design pattern. Each element of the vector is a single digit to the entire BigInt.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: Yeah, I already suspected you missed the necessary math basis. `< 9, 2334343, 235, 3, 243 >` are 5 perfectly decent digits in base 2^32. Of course, there's no digit "03" there. If anything, it's `0x00000003`.

Comment: @MSalters  I know what you are saying about doing the math in binary... I wasn't leaning towards that. I was leaning towards this: `vec1 <1,4,2,5,6,8,2> + vec2<3,9,5,7> = vec3<4,3,8,2,7,8,2>` but would actually be the value `2872834`

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I know what you're saying. The point is, in your design you carry to the right when you get a digit >=10. That's a waste of time and memory. Carry when you get a digit >=2^32. You'll have far fewer carries.

Comment: @MSalters OKay I see what you are saying; I'll have to come back at this and look at it on another day now that it's down on 'paper' to have a different perspective. Atm it is starting to get late and I'm a little too tired to do the actual math in my mind... It's just that I didn't want to lose the concepts that I had. I do appreciate all of your advise and positive criticism!

Comment: @MSalters I was about to close the page for the night; but right before I did the math came back to me... You are suggesting that each element of the vector can be as large as a `int` or `long` so a vector could be like this: `<12345689, 123456789>` + `<123456789, 123456789>` then each digit of the BigInt wouldn't be a 0-9 but each digit would be up to (2^32-1), but when multiplying wouldn't this lead to overflow?

Comment: To answer the above: yes, and maybe (not if you multiply as 64-bit for example, or use special instructions that store the overflow, useful for exactly these scenarios).  This is one reason why I suggested you work in base-256, until you start to understand how to manage things like overflow in 32-bit integers.  There's a clear knowledge gap here that's difficult to address as any kind of answer to your question.  Your main issue was needing to be space-efficient.  We've _repeatedly_ told you how to achieve that, and all that remains is for you to go try it, and learn along the way.

Comment: @paddy yeah at first it was a mental block; late in the evening and just not able to do the math in my mind. When I come back and look at it later, I'll have a different perspective on it. However some of the concepts will still stay the same. I like the idea of storing the digits in reverse order... But I think I see what you guys are saying. Instead of each individual digit of the BigInt being 0-9 such as `<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0>` each digit could actually be `<[0 - 2^32-1],[0 - 2^32-1],[0 - 2^32-1],...>`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we're saying.

Answer (score 0):

*-Update-*

Okay I took some advise and this is what I have so far. I have not yet incorporated the concept of storing the values in reverse order which shouldn't be all too difficult. As it currently stands, I have eliminated all of the outside classes and my BigInt class signature looks like this:

```
class BigInt {
private:
    short sign_;
    uint32_t carry_{0};
    std::vector<uint32_t> value_;

public:
    BigInt() : sign_( 0 ) {}

    BigInt(  const uint32_t* value, const std::size_t arraySize, short sign = 0 ) : 
    sign_( sign ) {
        if( sign_ != 0 ) sign_ = -1;
        value_.insert( value_.end(), &value[0], &value[arraySize] );
        std::reverse( value_.begin(), value_.end() );
    }

    BigInt( const std::vector<uint32_t>& value, short sign = 0 ) : 
    sign_( sign ) {
        if( sign_ != 0 ) sign_ = -1;
        value_.insert( value_.end(), value.begin(), value.end() );
        std::reverse( value_.begin(), value_.end() );
    }

    BigInt( std::initializer_list<uint32_t> values, short sign = 0 ) : 
    sign_( sign ) {
        if( sign_ != 0  ) sign_ = -1;
        value_.insert( value_.end(), values.begin(), values.end() );
        std::reverse( value_.begin(), value_.end() );
    }

    std::vector<uint32_t> operator()() {
        //value_.push_back( static_cast<uint32_t>( sign_ ) ); // causes negative to be pushed into container multiple times...
        std::reverse( value_.begin(), value_.end() );
        return value_;
    }
};
```

I think this is a good start: there are several ways to construct one which gives the caller some flexibility since you can create a BigInt with a pointer, an array, a vector, or even an initializer list. At first it may seem counter intuitive to have the sign at the end of the constructor but I want to be able to have the sign value to be a defaulted parameter when the value is positive. If anything other than `0` is passed in for the sign value it will convert it to `-1`. A little more time and I'll have the signature of this class complete then I can move onto the operators that will work on it.

There are some minor pitfalls in the above code but I'm continuously working on them.

Comment: The smallest addressable storage unit is `char`.  If you insist on templating your 'digit' type as a base-10 integral type, then you'll either need to accept wasting a lot of bits, or pack your numbers as BCD (i.e. two digits per byte) and index them in pairs.  If your math is lightweight and the main processing requirement is converting to/from base 10 then carry on.  If the main processing requirement is fast math and compact storage, then you are on the wrong track and you should use a base that is a power of 2 that can be packed into a native integral type.

Comment: @paddy I updated my answer with working code: it's not complete and bug free yet, but it is a work in progress. This class will basically only store the contents, manage its element ordering and checking for valid input. All of the operations on this I am planning on implementing in outside functions that will be friends with this class.